# Sumar 2 columnas y mostrar el resultado para cada fila. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

tengo el siguiente problema, deseo sumar dos columnas, como se ve en las imágenes, que recomiendan, hice algunas operaciones en el controlador pero no consigo resultados.

Esta es mi vista:

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" id="table-2">
  <thead>
    <th>Paciente</th>
    <th>Especialista</th>
    <th>Servicios</th>
    <th>Costo</th>
    <th>Detalles</th>
    <th>Pago a Cuenta</th>
    <th>Saldo</th>
    <th>Acciónes</th>
  </thead>
<tbody>
  @if(count($sale))
    @foreach($sale as $sales)
     <tr>
      <td>{{$sales->patient->full_name}}</td>
       <td>{{$sales->specialists->full_name}}</td>
       <td>@foreach($sales->services as $services){{$services->name}}<br>@endforeach</td>
       <td>@foreach($sales->services as $services){{$services->cost}}<br>@endforeach</td>
       <td>{{$sales->bill}}<br></td>
       <td>{{$sales->charged}}<br></td>
       <td>@foreach($sales->services as $services){{$services->cost}}<br>@endforeach-{{$sales->charged}}</td>
      {{--  <td>@if($sales->bill) <span class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>@else<span class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></span>@endif</td>  --}}
      {{--  <td>@if($sales->charged) <span class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>@else<span class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></span>@endif</td>  --}}
      <td>
      <a href="{{route('sale.edit', $sales->id)}}" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
          <a type="button" data-href="{{route('sale.destroy',$sales->id)}}" 
                  class="btn btn-round btn-danger btn-delete" 
                  data-confirm-text="Estas seguro de borrar?"
                  data-confirm-delete="Si"
                  title="Borrar" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                </a>
      </td>
  </tr>
    @endforeach
  @endif
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="ColVis">
{{ $sale->links() }}
</div>
```

Y este es mi controlador

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Sale;
use App\Http\Requests\SaveSale;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateSale;
use App\Patient;
use App\Specialist;
use App\Service;
// use App\Pieza;


class SaleController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('locale'); 
        $this->middleware('timezone'); 
        $this->middleware('permission:acceso.full.editar');
        $this->middleware('session.database', ['only' => ['sessions', 'invalidateSession']]);
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $sale = Sale::orderBy('id','asc')->paginate(10);
        if ( $request->ajax() ) {
            if (count($sale)) {
                return response()->json([
                    'success' => true,
                    'view'    => view('sale.list', compact('sale'))->render(),
                ]);
            } else {
                return response()->json([
                    'success' => false,
                    'message' => trans('app.no_records_found')
                ]);
            }
        }
        return view('sale.index', compact('sale'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $edit = false;
        $patients = Patient::all()->pluck('full_name2', 'id');
        $specialists = Specialist::all()->pluck( 'full_name','id');
        $services = Service::all()->pluck( 'name','id','cost');
        $sales = Sale::all()->pluck('bill','charged');
        // $pieza = Pieza::all()->pluck('nombre','id');
        return view('sale.create', compact('edit','patients','specialists', 'services','sales'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $sale = Sale::create($request->all());
        if ( $sale ) {
            $setservice = $sale->setService($sale->id,$request->service_id);


            return redirect()->route('sale.index', compact('sale'))->withSuccess('Venta creada con exito');

        } else {    
            return back()->withErrors($messages);   
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $edit = false;
        $patients = Patient::all()->pluck('full_name2', 'id');
        $specialists = Specialist::all()->pluck( 'full_name','id');
        $services = Service::all()->pluck( 'name','id','cost');
        // $piezas = Pieza::all()->pluck('nombre','descripcion','id');
        return view('sale.create', compact('edit','patients','specialists', 'services'));
        // $edit = false;
        // $patients = Patient::findOrFail($request->full_name);
        // $patients = Patient::all()->pluck('full_name2', 'id');
        // $specialists = Specialist::findOrFail($request->full_name2);
        // $specialists = Specialist::all()->pluck( 'full_name','id');
        // $services = Service::findOrFail($request->name);
        // $services = Service::all()->pluck( 'name','id','cost');
        // return view('sale.create', compact('edit','patients','specialists', 'services'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $sale = Sale::find($id)->update($request->all());
        if ( $sale ) {
                return redirect()->route('sale.index', compact('sale'))->withSuccess('Venta actualizada con exito');

        } else {    
            return back()->withErrors($messages);   
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
         $deletesale = Sale::find($id);
        if ( $deletesale->delete() ) {

            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'Venta eliminada',
            ]);
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'success'=> false,
                'message' => trans('app.error_again')
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function getServices()
    {
        $services = Service::all();
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'services' => $services
            ]);
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Bien hice la operación, dentro de list.blade.php

Agregue esto:

```
@php
       $total=$services->cost-$sales->charged
       @endphp
       <td>{{$total}}</td>
```

Sin embargo se debe sumar antes los costos por cliente como en la imagen: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]